# Magento: XML reference is ignored when targeting store view

Tags: xml, magento

I'm trying to remove a link from the account navigation per-store basis. Actually I'm removing two links, one from the default account navigation and one from a "custom" header navigation.

The remove action for the custom link kicks in and the link gets removed, but the remove action for the default account navigation is ignored.

If I add the remove action for the default account navigation inside the `<customer_logged_in>` handle it works just fine. So it only gets ignored when it's inside the store view handle.

I'm using the code below, in local.xml

```
<STORE_foo>
    <!-- Doesn't kick in -->
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>newsletter</name></action>
    </reference>

    <!-- Kicks in -->
    <reference name="customer_header_navigation" >
        <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>header_account_newsletter</name></action>
    </reference>
</STORE_foo>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the handles that fire on a customer account page

[image: default,STORE_default,THEME_frontend_default_default,customer_account_index,customer_logged_in,customer_account]

You can see the store handle (`STORE_default`) fires before the `customer_account_index` handle.  Layout XML Updates are processed in handle order.  So all the `default` handles run first (with `local.xml` last), then all the `STORE_default` handles run (again, with `local.xml` last), etc.

Since it's the the `customer_account_index` handle which adds the block `customer_account_navigation` to the page, your updates have no blocks to reference.

It works for `customer_logged_in`, since that handle fires after the `customer_account_index` handle.

Comment: I should have thought about that. Thanks Alan! The possibility to nest layout handles would be nice. `<STORE_foo><customer_account></customer_account></STORE_foo>`

Answer (score 1):

Well well, why didn't I think about this five hours ago? Go to "Admin / System / Config / Advanced" and turn off the Mage_Newsletter module for the store I want to remove the link from.